# Nextjs dynamic route page return 403 Forbidden error for only one specific user dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have my route defined as `patients/[userID].tsx` in pages dir.

When I tried to access one of the specific active userID (eg. patients/7917067d) it gave `403 Forbidden` error in prod only, In dev, it is working fine.

FYI, when I enter the wrong userId it gives 404 which is correct behaviour but don't know why only this userId which is correct gives a 403 error.

**NOTE: I am using Static Generation with Client-side data fetching**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the nextjs package to 12.3.3 did the work.

Refer this [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/45437#discussioncomment-4837260) for more details.